# Dymos: How to impose a constraint on a static output variable of ODE group at the phase level

Tags: openmdao

In my ODE system, I have a component to compute some quantity of interest based on the design variables, e.g., the weight of a device based on its dimensions (the dimensions are posed as design variables in optimization). I can add a constraint on this quantity at the system level using `add_constraint`, e.g.,

```
class ODESystem(om.Group):
...
def setup(self):
...
     self.add_subsystem(name='weight', subsys=Weight(), promotes_output=['W'])
     self.add_constraint('W', upper=4.0)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to add a constraint on this quantity at the phase level (in which the system participates) instead of at the system level? E.g.,

```
class ODESystem(om.Group):
...
def setup(self):
...
     self.add_subsystem(name='weight', subsys=Weight(), promotes_output=['W'])
...

phase = dm.Phase(ode_class=ODESystem ...)
# add constraint on 'W'
```

I tried `add_boundary_constraint` or `add_path_constraint` on 'W' but these failed because I guess they expect the quantity to have the same dimensions as the collocation nodes.

Note: Using `add_boundary_constraint` with an expression to compute the weight does work, but I'd like to keep the weight computation component as part of the ODESystem.

Comment: I think this is definitely a deficiency in that there's no "official dymos way" to do this at the moment, that is transcription-independent.

If you're using the radau transcription, you can add a constraint to the ode path:

```
p.add_constraint('traj.phase.rhs_all.weights.W', upper=4.0)
```
But that `rhs_all` path will be different for the others.

If weight is based on other dynamic vals, it seems like it would be difficult to guarantee that it is truly static.  If it is calculated based only upon parameters to the phase or trajectory, then compute it outside of the phase.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. The weight is only dependent on static parameters, so it makes sense to compute it outside of the phase. The reason why I thought about adding it at the phase level is because I'm trying to programmatically "turn on" certain constraints based on the user input and it'd be nice to have all the constraints in the same section of my code.

Comment: It's certainly something I'll think about implementing.  We have the `dymos.static_output` tag for ODE outputs that prevents them from being added to timeseries.  Perhaps we should collect these in `phase.static_outputs...` so they can be constrained uniformly across transcriptions.